# Does it require only subquery results for comparision operators ANY, SOME, or ALL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below `#1 SQL` works whereas `#2 SQL` not.

```
SELECT * FROM #MyTab WHERE ID >ANY (SELECT 1)

SELECT * FROM #MyTab WHERE ID >ANY (1,2)
```

The definition of the data\table is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTab 
(
ID INT, 
VALUE CHAR
)

INSERT INTO #MyTab (ID, VALUE) VALUES
(1,'A'), (2,'B'), (3,'C'), (4,'D'), (5,'E')
```

I want to understand if the `ANY`, `SOME`, `ALL` operators need only sub-query results as input for comparison ? 
... Like the EXISTS clause working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [**documenatation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx) you can use `any` operator only with `subquery`.

```
scalar_expression { = | < > | ! = | > | > = | ! > | < | < = | ! < } 
     { SOME | ANY } ( subquery )
```

Comment: @Aditya Yes, for `ALL` there is the same rule